# REST API works on localhost but does not on Server

Tags: php, mysql, rest

A couple of days ago I posted a question here, that I have a problem with my php REST API throwing a `500 internal server error.`

So I just figured I would try the same code on my localhost. (should have done that in first place I know) Anyway, it works on my local machine. So I am wondering now what could be the problem then?

Maybe some permissions are to low or I am missing some software?

What could I check to find out where my problem is?

Thanks for any tips in advance here is the original thread, with all the code and the error output:
[PHP Rest API readAll gives back empty response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25384619/php-rest-api-readall-gives-back-empty-response)

Comment: You have checked you have mod rewrite enabled; right?

Comment: `echo in_array('mod_rewrite', apache_get_modules())?'yes':'no';`

Comment: See .htdocs code in my other thread. Also if the URL rewrite would not work it wouldn`t it have a different error output like file not found?

Comment: Also I just tested it with your code, it says yes

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem myself.

The mysqli function `$stmt->get_results` requires the special mysqlidb driver to be installed, which wasn't the case on my server.